# State testing method Vs. Distinguished return value

Tags: java

while reading *Effective Java* book I found this guideline

> A class with a “state-dependent” method that can be invoked only under certain  unpredictable conditions should generally have a
>   separate “state-testing” method  indicating whether it is appropriate
>   to invoke the state-dependent method.For example, the Iterator
>   interface has the state-dependent method next() and the  corresponding
>   state-testing method hasNext().

Additionally there was one more guideline to choose 
**State testing method** or **Distinguished return value**

Book says:

> If an object is to be accessed concurrently without external synchronization or is subject to externally induced state transitions,
>   you must use a distinguished return value, as the object’s state could
>   change in the interval between the invocation of a state-testing
>   method and its state-dependent method.All other things being equal, a
>   state-testing method is mildly preferable to a distinguished return
>   value. It offers slightly better readability, and incorrect use may be
>   easier to detect: if you forget to call a state-testing method, the
>   state-dependent method will throw an exception, making the bug
>   obvious; if you forget to check for a distinguished return value, the
>   bug may be subtle.

My question is I find no distinction between State testing method  Vs. Distinguished return value. Both are serving same purpose. How forgetting Distinguished return value check can be subtle as compared to forgetting state test method check ?

Comment: Please edit your question. 1) Don't use **bold** for quotes, prefix them with `> `. 2) Use empty lines to separate paragraphs.

Comment: Your question explains the difference and when you must use one vs the other. Read about [race hazzards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).

Comment: If a method throws an exception and you forget to catch it, then your application crashes. If you get an error in a return value and you forgot to check it, then your application continues running without ever indicating there was a problem. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @mikez You made picture clear

Answer (score 2):

An example of state testing vs distinguished return value:

Assuming something like `getNext()` as in the original quote, state testing will be something like having a `boolean hasNext()`, and a `Foo getNext()` and if there is no next element to get, calling `getNext()` will throw an "no next object exception"

For distinguished return value it will be something like if there is no next element, `getNext()` is going to return a special value (e.g. null, or an empty object).

In case you forget to call `hasNext()`, calling a `getNext()` without next element will give you obvious problem: an exception will be thrown

However for case of distinguished value, your code may still works if you forget to check the distinct value:

```
Foo foo = bar.getNext();
// you should have something like if (foo != null) here
doSomethingWithFoo(foo);
somethingElseWithFoo(foo);
```

You may get subtle error like NPE deep in `somethingElseWithFoo(foo)`, or something even subtler depending how it is used.